# Import Word File name and data into Excel in a consistent format

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple Word files. I would like to import them in such a way that the name of the file comes in Cell A1 followed by the data in cells A2:A8 for example. Then I want the next Word file in the folder to import the file name into cell B2 and then the data in Cells B2:B8.

The data in a particular word file looks like this:

```
Z3CC07002466
ZAIC07000270
ZRHC07003384
Z9HC07000576
Z8FC07002646
Z6EC07000339
Z6NC07000746
```

I want to import multiple files into one Excel sheet with each Word file data next to each other.

[image]

Can VBA enable me to do this with a folder with multiple docs inside it?

Comment: I can't help you with your question, but you should upload that image to here.

Comment: is the word document content a sequence of lines or a table?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the word documents have a very simple formal, as a sequence of lines. If the words are stored in a word table, different story. Create and execute this Macro:

```
Sub fromWordDocsToMultiCols()
    Dim f As String: f = "c:\SO\"
    Dim s As String: s = Dir(f & "*.docx")
    Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim col As Integer: col = 1

    On Error GoTo errHandler
    Do Until s = ""
        Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(f & s)
        wdDoc.Range.Copy
        Sheet1.Cells(1, col).Value = s
        Sheet1.Cells(2, col).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        wdDoc.Close False: col = col + 1: s = Dir
    Loop

errHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox Err.Description
    If Not wdApp Is Nothing Then wdApp.Quit False
End Sub
```